# Travis-CI is unable to open file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to build my iOS project, but travis-ci is printing following error message:

> /Users/travis/build/BilalReffas/Analyzer/Pods/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-Analyzer/Pods-Analyzer.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file
>   (in target "Analyzer" in project "Analyzer") (in target 'Analyzer')

Of course I selected my scheme as shared. It's possible for me to build the project locally. I don't understand why travis is not finding the `debug.xcconfig` file.

```
My Podfile:

  platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Analyzer' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Charts' 

end
```

My travis.yml:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode10
xcode_workspace: Analyzer.xcworkspace 
xcode_scheme: Analyzer
xcode_destination: platform=iOS Simulator,OS=12.0,name=iPad Pro (9.7-inch)
podfile: Podfile
before_install:
  - gem install cocoapods
  - pod install --repo-update
```

After debugging I used ssh to check the file permission.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 travis  staff    662 Nov  3 14:41 Pods-Analyzer.debug.xcconfig
```

As you see this should be totally fine to top open the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Travis. It's a weird bug from [cocoapods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8091). Adding `gem install cocoapods --pr` to your `travis.yml` should fix it.

My current travis.yml:

```
language: swift
osx_image: xcode10.1
xcode_workspace: Analyzer.xcworkspace 
xcode_scheme: Analyzer
xcode_destination: platform=iOS Simulator,OS=12.1,name=iPad Pro (9.7-inch)
podfile: Podfile
before_install:
  - gem install cocoapods --pre
  - pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open project settings and update path to debug or release xcconfig:

[image]